# Making a brick wall

Tags: python, python-turtle

Alright so i got this wall but i wanna know how i can make it so that the even bricks are horizontal and not vertical [I want the wall pattern to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPMJt.png)

Heres my code so far:

```
def drawCustomBrickWall(rows, cols, brickWidth, brickHeight, mortarWidth):
    for row in range(rows):
      for col in range(cols):
          x = row * (brickWidth + (mortarWidth * 0.25))
          y = col * (brickHeight + (mortarWidth * 4))
          if x % 2 == 0:
            drawRect(x, y, brickWidth * 0.5, brickHeight * 2)
          else:
            drawRect(x, y, brickWidth, brickHeight)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking odd and even but there are three cases so we need to think modulus 3 instead:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BRICK_WIDTH = 20
MORTAR_WIDTH = 5

def drawCustomBrickWall(rows, cols, brickWidth, brickHeight, mortarWidth):
    for row in range(rows):
        for col in range(cols):
            modulus = col % 3
            offset = (col - modulus) / 3

            x = offset * (brickWidth + brickHeight + mortarWidth*2)
            y = row * (brickWidth + mortarWidth)

            match modulus:
                case 0: drawRect(x, y, brickHeight, brickWidth)
                case 1: drawRect(x + brickHeight + mortarWidth, y, brickWidth, brickHeight)
                case 2: drawRect(x + brickHeight + mortarWidth, y + brickHeight + mortarWidth, brickWidth, brickHeight)

def drawRect(x, y, width, height):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.penup()

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()

drawCustomBrickWall(3, 10, BRICK_WIDTH, (BRICK_WIDTH - MORTAR_WIDTH) / 2, MORTAR_WIDTH)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

You can replace the `match` statement with a series of `if ... then` statements, if you prefer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that creates a brick wall for you,
in future can you make sure you use the Code Sample to display code like I have done bellow,

```
def drawCustomBrickWall(rows, cols, brickWidth, brickHeight, mortarWidth):
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        x = col * (brickWidth + (mortarWidth * 0.25))
        y = row * (brickHeight + (mortarWidth * 4))
        
        if y % 2 == 0:
            drawRect(x, y, brickWidth, brickHeight)
        else:
            drawRect(x, y, brickWidth * 0.5, brickHeight * 2)
```